# cv2.circle int() arguement must be a string or number, not 'tuple'

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to make a code to put a circle on screen with certain coordinates that are already defined.
Here's my code.

```
cv2.circle(filtered_C1,(int(centroid_x_C1),int(centroid_y_C1)),5,(255,255,255),-1)
```

Whenever I run my code, I always get TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'
I've fixed the parenthesis many times but to no avail.

Comment: Check values of `centroid_x_C1` and `centroid_y_C1`…

Answer (score 0):

when using the .read function make sure that you are using two variables, ex:

```
var3 = VideoCapture(0)
var, var2 = var3.read()
```

use the second variable in the functions that you were doing.